# Splitting or Breakup multidimensional arrays in scala spark along attributes

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

```
var date_columns = df.dtypes.filter(_._2 == "TimestampType")
```

This creates a two dimensional array containing only timestamp type column names along with their datatepyes

Array[(String, String)] = Array((cutoffdate,TimestampType), (wrk_pkg_start_date,TimestampType), (wrk_pkg_end_date,TimestampType))

Now, how do i split this array such that only columns names are in an array

dateColumns = [ cutoffdate , wrk_pkg_start_date , wrk_pkg_end_date ]

in Scala Spark . Without using for loops please

Comment: Can't you just `map` over it? `date_columns.map(_.getString(0)).collect()`

Comment: value getString is not a member of (String, String) thats the error

Comment: `df.dtypes.filter(_._2 == "TimestampType").map(_._1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `collect` for that

```
var date_columns = df.dtypes.collect{ case (name, "TimestampType") => name }
```

`collect` can `filter` array using *pattern matching* and `map` elements

see [scala documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#collect%5BB%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5BA,B%5D)(implicitevidence$9:scala.reflect.ClassTag%5BB%5D):Array%5BB%5D)

Comment: the question is if i have array [{String , String)] type , is there a direct method to split it into  [(String)] , [(String)] arrays .

Comment: @Leothorn so, if you need just split `Array[(String , String)] ` you can use `unzip`: 
`val (names, types) = df.dtypes.unzip`

Comment: thst dolves the problrm